# .net Highcharts can't show the bar chart correctly in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts, highcharts

i am trying to show a report using bar chart with highchart.as you can see here in mycontroller i have :

```
var q =
            _iTrafficRepository.Get()
                .AsEnumerable().GroupBy(i => i.SubmitDateTime.Date)
                .Select(g => new {date= g.Key, count = g.Count()}).ToArray();
        Highcharts chartTraffcBarDatetime = new Highcharts("chart1")

  .SetSeries(new Series
  {
      Type = ChartTypes.Bar,
      Name = "Browser share",
      Data = new Data(q)
  });

        ViewBag.ChartTraffic = chartTraffc;
        ViewBag.chartTraffcBarDatetime = chartTraffcBarDatetime;

        return View();
```

The `q` just count the submitdatetime ,the result of this :
[image]

In the view i used this code:

```
 DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chartTraffcBarDatetime = ViewBag.chartTraffcBarDatetime;
                <div style="direction: ltr">@(chartTraffcBarDatetime)</div>
```

But the result :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To access the 'chartTraffcBarDatetime' variable in the view, you need to use braces @{} not paranentheses @() ...

Try this:

```
DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chartTraffcBarDatetime = ViewBag.chartTraffcBarDatetime;
            <div style="direction: ltr">@{chartTraffcBarDatetime}</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work .causes an error : Compiler Error Message: CS1528: Expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration)

Comment: Are you using Razor view engine? Perhaps if you showed us all the markup in the view then we can get more perspective...

Comment: Please copy the entire view markup into the question so we can better assist you :)